# Source and authentication of "Jihad Will Be Performed Until The Coming of the Hour"

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity, jihad

الجهاد ماض إلى قيام الساعة

Jihad Will Be Performed Until The Coming of the Hour

Where is this hadith from and what is the authenticity of this hadith?

Answer (score 5):

Its meaning is correct and supported in many other ways as well.

From the Koran:

> وَقَاتِلُوهُمْ حَتَّىٰ لَا تَكُونَ فِتْنَةٌ وَيَكُونَ الدِّينُ كُلُّهُ
>   لِلَّـهِ
>
> *And fight them **until there is no fitnah and [until] the religion, all of it, is for Allah** .*
>
> [Al-Anfal 39](https://quran.com/8/39)

This will happen when Jesus (Isa) returns near the Day of Judgement when all religions except Islam would perish, see Surah An-Nisa 159 and Hadith on Isa and Dajjal. So Jihad must continue till then.

From Hadith:

> يقاتل عليه عصابة من المسلمين حتى تقوم الساعة
>
> *A group of people from the Muslims will fight until the Hour is established.*
>
> [Sahih Muslim 1922](https://sunnah.com/muslim/33/248)

> لا تزال طائفة من أمتي يقاتلون على الحق ظاهرين على من ناوأهم حتى يقاتل
>   آخرهم المسيح الدجال
>
> *A section of my community will continue to fight for the Truth and overcome their opponents till the last of them fights with the
>   Dajjal.*
>
> [Sahih Sunan Abu Dawud 2484](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/15/8)

> ‏لا هجرة بعد الفتح ولكن جهاد ونية
>
> *There is no Migration after the Conquest of Mecca, but Jihad and good intention remain*
>
> [Sahih Bukhari 2783](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/2)

Answer (score 2):

The hadith with the closest wording to that what you quoted is [this](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/15/56) one from Sunnan Abi Dawod, which was qualified as da'if by al-Albani:

> Three things are the roots of faith: to refrain from (killing) a person who utters, "There is no god but Allah" and not to declare him unbeliever whatever sin he commits, and not to excommunicate him from Islam for his any action; and **jihad will be performed continuously since the day Allah sent me as a prophet until the day the last member of my community will fight with the Dajjal** (Antichrist). The tyranny of any tyrant and the justice of any just (ruler) will not invalidate it. One must have faith in Divine decree.

The hadith was also compiled by al-Bayhaqi in his al-Qada' wa al-Qadar  القضاء والقدر  -see [here](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=675&pid=333447&hid=145) in Arabic-  and in his as-Sunan al-Kubra -see [here](http://islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=71&ID=17912) in Arabic- via the narrator chain of abu Dawod and among those who compiled it too you may find Sa'id ibn Mansoor (the teacher of abu Dawod) -see [here](https://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=70&pid=32815&hid=2207) in Arabic-, abu Ya'ala and a-Daylami. The hadith has two issues in the narrator chain: Ja'afr ibn Burqan جَعْفَرُ بْنُ بُرْقَانَ is considered as somewhat trustworthy, but making mistakes in his narrations from imam az-Zuhri and Yazid ibn abi Nushbah يَزِيدَ بْنِ أَبِي نُشْبَةَ is unknown. Even if the hadith's authenticity is rather weak, al-Mundhiri didn't comment on it as stated in Aabadi's 'Awan al_Ma'abud عون المعبود, there are some sound ahadith that support its meaning, like:

- > Good is tied to the forelock of the horses. It Was said to him: Messenger of Allah, why is it so? He (the Prophet said): For reward and booty until the Day of Judgment. (See for example in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/33/146))

This hadith was also compiled by al-Bukhari under a chapter entitled: Jihad is to be carried on whether the Muslim ruler is good or bad الْجِهَادُ مَاضٍ مَعَ الْبَرِّ وَالْفَاجِرِ -see [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/68)-.

- > "Some people from my followers will continue to be victorious over others till Allah's Order (The Hour) is established." ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/85))
- > The Prophet (ﷺ) said, on the day of the Conquest of Mecca, "There is no migration (after the Conquest), but Jihad and good intentions, and when you are called for Jihad, you should immediately respond to the call." ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3077) and in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/15/506))

beside many ahadith starting with:

> The Last Hour would not come unless you fight  ... (see for example: in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/54/76), [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/141), and many more)

So far a few examples from the sunnah.

The Qur'an supports the meaning more as Jihad is prescribed as any other deed and is at least fard kifaya, and as the hadith says:

> ‘What is lawful is that which Allah has permitted, in His Book and what is unlawful is that which Allah has forbidden in His Book. What He remained silent about is what is pardoned.’” ([Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1334930))

among the verses supporting that Jihad will last until the last hour you may find:

- > Indeed, Allah has purchased from the believers their lives and their properties [in exchange] for that they will have Paradise. They fight in the cause of Allah , so they kill and are killed. [It is] a true promise [binding] upon Him in the Torah and the Gospel and the Qur'an. And who is truer to his covenant than Allah ? So rejoice in your transaction which you have contracted. And it is that which is the great attainment. ([9:111](https://legacy.quran.com/9/111))
- > Fight them until there is no [more] fitnah and [until] worship is [acknowledged to be] for Allah . But if they cease, then there is to be no aggression except against the oppressors. ([2:193](https://legacy.quran.com/2/193))
- > Fight those who do not believe in Allah or in the Last Day and who do not consider unlawful what Allah and His Messenger have made unlawful and who do not adopt the religion of truth from those who were given the Scripture - [fight] until they give the jizyah willingly while they are humbled. ([9:29](https://legacy.quran.com/9/29))
- > And fight them until there is no fitnah and [until] the religion, all of it, is for Allah . And if they cease - then indeed, Allah is Seeing of what they do. ([8:39](https://legacy.quran.com/8/39))
- > Fighting has been enjoined upon you while it is hateful to you. But perhaps you hate a thing and it is good for you; and perhaps you love a thing and it is bad for you. And Allah Knows, while you know not. ([2:216](https://legacy.quran.com/2/216))

Answer (score 1):

First of all a disclaimer: I am not a scholar, I just did a google search.

The closest thing I could find to what you quoted are these words:

الجهاد ماضٍ إلى يوم القيامة

It is essentially the same statement with the same sentence structure, except that  يوم القيامة  is used instead of قيام الساعة to indicate the end of time. This is from a bigger hadith in Mu'jam al-Awsat of Al-Tabarani, hadith number 4775.

From what I understand, this particular hadith is a weak hadith, however everywhere it says that the meaning is correct since there are other versions that essentially say the same thing. This is also kind of obvious as fighting is an obligation in Islam:

> [2:216](https://quran.com/2/216) Jihad (holy fighting in Allah's Cause) is ordained for you (Muslims) though you dislike it, and it may be that you dislike a thing which is good for you and that you like a thing which is bad for you. Allah knows but you do not know.

And Jihad is a more general form of fighting, and like other obligations it would remain until the end of times.